# Using Date.getDay with Angular TS2554 Expected 0 arguments but got 1

Tags: angular, date, error-handling

I'm trying to get the number for the first weekday of a month by defining firstWeekDay inside the component like this:

```
date = new Date();
firstWeekDay = this.date.getDay(this.date.getDate(1));
```

When I compile, I get the error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. When I actually print the value of the variable to the console, I get the correct output.

Any idea how to fix or handle this?

Kind Regards
Fonzane

Comment: Please share all relevant code snippets. The code above seems incomplete.

Comment: If `date` is a `Date` object, then, as the error notes [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) does not take any arguments. Neither does [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) for that matter. We'll need to know what `date` is supposed to hold to help though.

Comment: I'm sorry, I supplemented the missing piece. You were right though, date is a Date object. Is there any other way to use these methods?